# Framer Motion exit animation with useAnimate() and useEffect() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

I'm trying to implement exit animation with the new way using `useAnimate` hook and `useEffect` but for some reason its not firing up.

Here's my code inside the `useEffect` function:

```
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
  const [isPresent, safeToRemove] = usePresence();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPresent) {
      const enterAnimation = async () => {
        await animate([
          [
            "#title",
            { opacity: [0, 1], y: [-20, 0] },
            { duration: 0.5, delay: stagger(0.2) },
          ],
          [
            "#text",
            { opacity: [0, 1], y: [-20, 0] },
            { duration: 0.5, delay: stagger(0.2) },
          ],
        ]);
      };
      enterAnimation();
    } else {
      const exitAnimation = async () => {
        await animate(
          "#title",
          { opacity: [1, 0], y: [0, 20] },
          { duration: 0.5 },
        );
        safeToRemove();
        console.log("exited");
      };
      exitAnimation();
    }
  }, [selectedTab]);
```

... and here's my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/runtime-surf-cgn4d8?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A10%2C24&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz000a3b6goq5y94bb%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00023b6g5j0tq7lq%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00073b6gfkz9r9bo%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00093b6gthzlpa4g%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B55.444696912589784%252C44.555303087410216%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpzhngbz00023b6g5j0tq7lq%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00023b6g5j0tq7lq%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzih6ah00023b6g8afgqho6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A24%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A24%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fpage.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpzih6ah00023b6g8afgqho6%2522%257D%252C%2522clpzhngbz00093b6gthzlpa4g%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00083b6gwkop0cff%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00093b6gthzlpa4g%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00083b6gwkop0cff%2522%257D%252C%2522clpzhngbz00073b6gfkz9r9bo%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00073b6gfkz9r9bo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00033b6gukg9svn3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00043b6g5jqnn5xe%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00053b6gwu58sxtx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00063b6gekky8jyw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522install%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpzhngbz00033b6gukg9svn3%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) so you can see the markup, how i use `<AnimatePresence>` and anything else.

Any help would be appreciated!